# Threads disappeared on DLL ExitInstance

Tags: c++, windows

I have a windows DLL with functions InitInstance and ExitInstance.
The DLL creates some threads, worker threads with _beginthreadex and threads with Message Queue,
derived from CWinThread (MFC).

The DLL should useable by any application.

I wrote a small host application for this DLL to test and it worked fine, except
when i close this host application without calling FreeLibrary before. In this case, ExitInstance
is called as well, but all threads are disappeard, which is quite unusual and leads to a deadlock
as some routines waiting for a thread finished which does not exist any longer - as it was
finished or killed.
I need to go this way (skip to call FreeLibrary) in order to simulate what could hapen when
other applications use this DLL.

ExitInstance is called, but all threads which
normally still running are disappeared - most probably because DLL is handled somehow differently
when unloaded from host process if you do not call FreeLibrary before.

They disappear silently, for instance, if a thread just implements a loop with a WaitForSingleObject within loop, this thread is not finish normally.

```
thread()
{
    while(running == true)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(...);
    }
    threadfinished=true; /// 1
}
```

If calling FreeLibrary before closing application, code section 1 is called.
When closing application without calling FreeLibrary before, code section 1 is never called
but loop also not running any longer as thread was removed.

How should I handle this situation ? Thank you

Comment: A thread is part of a process. If the process exits then its threads will also be killed. If you want to have a thread continue to run after its process exits, you have to "detach" it from the process.

Comment: Hello,i need to terminate threads properly before process exits. How to detach them before process exits ? The threads killed that's right and in this situation the stack is above DLL_PROCESS_DETACH. What i need is some function indicating that process is about to be detached. Is this possible ?

Comment: Why would FreeLibrary not be called?

Comment: Because this DLL can be used in any application.

Comment: Threads don't just disappear.  Your code snippet is very broken, there's no escape from a while(1) loop without a *break*.  The threadfinished variable will never be set to true.  Clearly you'll need to spend more time debugging to find out what is going on.

Comment: You are right, the snipped was not complete. Have corrected this above. In my app there is also a real break condition. But the problem is, the threads disappear. The thread is created within DLL. FreeLibrary not called -> thread does not terminates normally

Comment: What do you expect to happen? The process that loaded the dll exits. The dll will be removed from memory, all threads will be killed. Do you want them to run, even after the application exits? What do you expect to happen if multiple programs run the dll? You sound like you expect the dll to somehow stay resident and share data. That does not happen, at least not by default.

Comment: I expect the threads to be terminated in the normal way. The ExitInstance of DLL is called. Within exit instance stop threads is initiated, for instance set running=false in the loop above or Post an exit message to CWinThread. But at this point - threads are already killed. This is the problem. If the process would already be killed, why still ExitInstance called ? SO the process at this point still is running

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: Your assumption is a bit tricky. On Windows, [a thread that is still running may prevent the process from exiting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/27/10054832.aspx). We don't know in this case how the host process tries to exit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exit thread upon deleting static object during unload DLL causes deadlock?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441048/exit-thread-upon-deleting-static-object-during-unload-dll-causes-deadlock) During process termination, threads are killed first, then DLL_PROCESS_DETACH is sent. In that case, you shouldn't try to wait for threads to run down because they've already been killed.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `CWinThread::ExitInstance` is very clear: "Do not call this member function from anywhere but within the `Run` member function." (i.e. `CWinThread::Run`, the thread itself).

Obviously, that means Windows is NOT going to call `ExitInstance` for you. Nor is the host application, since that has no idea about your threads.

What *is* called is `DllMain`, but only once and with argument `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`. You won't get `DLL_THREAD_DETACH` because that happens *after* your threads exit cleanly (i.e. `ExitInstance` or returning from `CWinThread::Run`).

By the way, consider what code your threads could be running after your DLL has been unloaded. It can't be your functions or MFC, since those functions no longer exists. The thread would crash with an Access Violation because its instruction pointer now points to unallocated memory.